# Does anyone have information on liquid immersion for BTC mining?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, mining-setup

I was looking into cooling costs of Bitcoin mining, and air cooling has many problems. It isn't very efficient, it is noisy, dust and other particles can get sucked into the machines leading to extra maintenance over time, etc. I have been hearing about this liquid immersion cooling, I wanted to know if it is viable. Does it take up a lot of space? Is the equipment too expensive, or does it pay itself off over air cooling? Are there modifications that are required to the mining hardware to make sure it functions smoothly? How easy are these systems to set up? Do they take up a lot of extra space vertically or horizontally?

Lastly, how does it compare to non-immersion water cooling?

I know this might be a lot to unpack, so if you have any little bits of information that would be appreciated otherwise, I will be researching independently. I just figured I would reach out here in case anyone had some solid information on it they could share with me.

Thanks.